# React posting form data and rendering data from database

Tags: reactjs, forms, api

I'm new to react. I have a POST API which takes the User's Name and email ID as an input and returns that specific user's details . I want to submit the username and email ID via a form as request and after submission, I want to render the user details i.e, User's Name, email ID, age etc in the React UI as a table. The API works fine and returns the required response. How do I go about solving this problem?

React CODE :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users: [],
            username: '',
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleUserNameChange = e => {
        this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
    }


    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newUser = {
            username: this.state.username,
        };


    }

    componentDidMount() {
         axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/users', newUser)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Saved');
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(this.state.username);
            });
    }




    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <div>
                  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                      <label>User Name</label>
                      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleUserNameChange} />

                      <button type="submit">Add</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{this.state.username}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @vipulp I've added what I've tried so far.

Comment: can you also post the response coming after the post request? Just to confirm, you want to render the details coming in response, right?

Comment: @vipulp  I'm able to get the output in my console. But I'm not able to render the same output in my UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a following way. This is just a basic implementation. Modify as you need.

1) You'll have two `input` fields for `username` and `email ID` in form.

```
state={
   username: '',
   emailID: '',

   // also define states for response data user's name, age etc.
 }
```

Also have one `handleEmailChange` function similar to `handleUserNameChange` for emailID.

2) Make the post request in `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newUser = {
        username: this.state.username,
        emailID: this.state.emailID
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/users', newUser)
        .then(response => {           
            this.setState({}) // get age, name and other data from response and set 
                              //  the states here respectively 
        })
        .catch(error => error);            
}
```

3) Render in a table

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email ID</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{this.state.name}</td>
    <td>{this.state.emailID}</td>
    <td>{this.state.age}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```